# Undefined references to base template class' methods

Tags: c++, templates, undefined-reference

I have a bunch of things mixed, and they all lead to undefined references. Please, excuse me for simply dropping the code, but, since I don't know which are the individual problems, I can't search for them.

### c.hpp

```
// A public class
class C {
private:
    // This class is private because it is used just for convenience;
    // it is not part of C's interface. Its methods are not defined because
    // the types for which it will be instantiated are known.
    template<typename T> 
    class Base {
    private:
        T* variable;
    public:
        // Note that this method should be available to C users, i.e., it
        // is part of the interface. Should Base then be in the public
        // section of C?
       T* get() const noexcept;
    };
    
public:
    // Users of this class do not care how Derived1 and Derived2 are
    // implemented. Since they were very similar in nature (think of
    // them as the various iterator versions), I decided that it would
    // be better to let the shared code be in a common template which
    // was then instantiated for a set of known parameters.
    class Derived1 : public Base<char> {
    public:
        int function() noexcept;
    };
        
    class Derived2 : public Base<int> {
        /* ... */
    };
};

// Should the following be included? Would it avoid unneeded implicit instantiations,
// or are those already avoided because C::Base's methods are declared but not defined?
extern template C::Base<char>;
extern template C::Base<int>;
```

### c.cpp

```
template<typename T> 
T* C::Base<T>::get() const noexcept {
    return this->variable;
}

// This approach serves to hide the implementation and to shorten build times,
// while maintaining the flexibility of templates. Or so I believe.
template class C::Base<char>;
template class C::Base<int>;

// This should be another question, but... is this the correct place for
// class method attributes? There isn't much information about attributes.
[[gnu::visibility("default")]]
int C::Derived1::function() noexcept {
    return 7;
}
```

When the code is compiled under `default` visibility, it all compiles, links and runs fine. However, if visibility is switched to `hidden`, which is what I want to achieve, there are linking errors:

> undefined reference to `C::Base<char>::get() const`
>
> undefined reference to `C::Base<int>::get() const`

The rest of the code links fine, because all functions are marked with the appropiate visibility attribute, as shown. Since the public functions of `C::Base` are intended to be part of the exposed interface, they should be marked with `default` visibility too, but I don't know how. For instance, all of the following seems to be forbidden:

```
// This is not possible because templates are not "real" entities
[[gnu::visibility("default")]]
template<typename T>
T* C::Base<T>::get() const noexcept {
    return this->variable;
}


// But it isn't possible to specify it here either!
[[ /*error*/ ]] template [[ /*error*/ ]] class [[ /*error*/ ]]
    C::Base<int> [[ /*error*/ ]];
```

I have also tried to specify the attribute in the declaration of the methods:

```
class C {
private:
    template<typename T> 
    class Base {
    private:
        /* ... */
    
    public:
        [[gnu::visibility("default")]]
        T* get() const noexcept;
    };

    /* ... */
};
```

but it didn't change anything.

Could you please explain what is happening, covering the concerns expressed in the comments? Specifically, how and where should the visibility attribute be specified?

Comment: I have found some hints: [this GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17470), [this other GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21243), and [this other one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51930).

Comment: The problem is the implicit instantiation of `Base` that goes on when `Derived1` and `Derived2` are declared: `Base`'s methods have not yet been _defined_, hence the undefined references. Explicit template _declaration_ would prevent this, but, as explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation), "_explicit instantiation can only appear in the enclosing namespace of the template_", so it wouldn't be possible to prevent that. Perhaps with a helper namespace...