# C++ - undefined reference to Base class operator

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have a template base class Vect, from which VectDynamic is derived.

Base class (Vect.h):

```
template <typename Elem>
class Vect
{
public:
    virtual Elem& operator[](std::ptrdiff_t);
};
```

Derived class (VectDynamic.h):

```
#include "Vect.h"

template <typename Elem>
class VectDynamic: public Vect<Elem>
{
    std::size_t _dim;
    Elem* _val;
public:
    explicit VectDynamic(std::size_t dim = 0): _dim(dim), _val(new Elem[dim]) {}
    VectDynamic(std::size_t, const Elem&);
    VectDynamic(const VectDynamic&); 
    Elem& operator[](std::ptrdiff_t) override;
};

template <typename Elem>
VectDynamic<Elem>::VectDynamic(std::size_t size, const Elem& e):
    _dim(size), _val(new Elem[size]) 
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) _val[i] = e;
}

template <typename Elem>
VectDynamic<Elem>::VectDynamic(const VectDynamic& v): 
    _dim(v._dim), _val(new Elem[v._dim])
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v._dim; ++i) _val[i] = v._val[i];
}

template <typename Elem>
Elem& VectDynamic<Elem>::operator[] (std::ptrdiff_t i) 
{
    if (std::size_t(i) >= _dim)
        throw std::out_of_range("VectDynamic : Index out of range");
    return _val[i];
}
```

When I try to create an instance of the derived class like this (main.cpp):

```
#include "VectDynamic.h"

int main()
{
    VectDynamic<double> v1(5, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

I end up having this error from both classes:
`undefined reference to 'VectDynamic<double>::operator[](long)'`

Now I know many posts talk about this kind of error, but after hours of searching I couldn't find any reason why it would happen in my case.
I don't think the error would come from the way I includes the files, as it doesn't work either when everything is in a single file.

I've read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441848/undefined-references-to-base-template-class-methods) post that it might be due to the the implicit instantiation of the base class that goes on when the derived class is declared since the base class's methods aren't defined yet.

Do you think that is the problem ?
What would be a decent workaround ?

**EDIT**: Forgot to add the `operator[]` from the child, added it now (it wasn't causing any error as it was in my code).

Comment: Why don't you have `=0` on the base class operator declaration (since you seem to not want it defined)?

Comment: Make `Vect` `operator[]` pure virtual?

Comment: Thank you both, that fixed it, though I don't understand why the problem didn't appear sooner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `Vect<double>::operator[]` will never get called, the base vtable must be used for a moment during construction of the derived object and as you declared things, the base vtable has a pointer to that undefined method. That should be solved by adding "=0" (commonly described as "pure virtual") to the declaration of the base method.

Change to

```
template <typename Elem>
class Vect
{
public:
    virtual Elem& operator[](std::ptrdiff_t)=0;
};
```

Comment: I put your comment in the answer, so I could upvote with a clear conscience.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how making the base class pure will change anything about the definition of the child `operator[]`?

Comment: @MarkB did you notice the explanation that Bathsheba helpfully copied from my earlier comment into my answer?  Making that base function pure does does change the derived function, it changes the base vtable.  The derived constructor uses the base constructor, which uses the base vtable.  The original error was coming from the base vtable.  That use of the base vtable accomplishes nothing and could be removed by an optimizer.  But depending on its removal is incorrect.

Comment: @JSF I've read the error message about five times now and it says, as far as I can tell, undefined reference to `VectDynamic<double>::operator[](long)`, in other words the child operator function body itself. This is orthogonal to any vtable concerns that may ALSO exist.

Comment: @MarkB, Sorry, you were correct.  I saw an error but missed the bigger error.

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems pretty clear that you just didn't define `VectDynamic<double>::operator[]`. If you don't want the [] operator just remove the function declarations. If you do want it, you'll need to implement it.

Note that since it's a template class you can't implement the operator in a non-header source file.

And now that I've said all that, let me just also point out since you don't (correctly) follow the rule of 0, 3, or 5 you'll be leaking memory; is there a reason you aren't using `std::vector`?

Comment: I don't follow the rule of three/five/zero in this code because I only copied the part which caused my problem. There is no particular reason why I don't use `std::vector`, it's just that what I'm using is working fine for me so I didn't feel the need to find something else